# How create new instances for all setters methods in class?

Tags: java, class, initialization, setter

I have this code

```
private PT_DSP def_PT = new PT_DSP();
...
    def_PT.setVRTK(new VRTK());
    def_PT.getVRTK().setFILTER(new FILTER()); 
    def_PT.getVRTK().getFILTER().setMaskaTK(new MaskaTK());
    def_PT.getVRTK().getFILTER().getMaskaTK().setIdVer1(new IdVer1());
...
```

How can I create new instance for ALL setters in class def_PT on (new ...()), example FOR loop?
Or how can I read all setters in class to array ready for invoke?
Not Bean method.
THX

Comment: the problem here is that you want to call setters of other classes. If all the setters were in one class, perhaps this was doable with Apache BeanUtils. but like this is way more complex.

Comment: Methods don't need initialization, but data members do, and there are already two ways to do that without using setter methods at all. Unclear what you're asking,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that look at [`Method Chaining`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and change method in your class. With that you can try doing something like

```
private PT_DSP def_PT = new PT_DSP().setVRTK(new VRTK().setFILTER(new FILTER()...);
```

In method chaining each method in the class, always returns the current instance so that you can use it invoke other method in it.

Comment: I know only def_PT and I need initialize all setters in def_PT. VRTK, FILTER, MaskaTK are examples. I dont know how many setters are in def_PT.

Answer (score 0):

you could use reflection and call all setters of the parameters recursive

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

...

```
class Filter {
public void setMask(Mask mask){
    System.out.println("Mask set");
}
public void doSmth(){}

}
```

...

```
class Mask {
}
```

...

```
class PT_DSP {
    public void setFilter(Filter filter){
        System.out.println("Filter set");
    }
    public void doSmth(){}
}
```

...

```
public class SetterTest {


    private PT_DSP def_PT = new PT_DSP();

    @Test
    public void init() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        initSetters(def_PT);
    }

    public void initSetters(Object next) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {

        Method[] methods = next.getClass().getMethods();

        for(Method method : methods){
            if (method.getName().contains("set")){

                System.out.println(method.getName());
                Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();

                // parameters of setter
                List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Class type : parameterTypes) {

                    // generate new instance of parameter
                    Object object = type.newInstance();

                    // add parameter, for setter call later on
                    parameters.add(object);

                    // call recursive for parameter setters
                    initSetters(object);
                }
                // call setter, with new instane of target
                method.invoke(next.newInstance(), parameters.toArray());

            }
        }
    }


}
```

> setFilter
>
> setMask
>
> Mask set
>
> Filter set

Comment: On the line where is getParameterCount() is "The method getParameterCount() is undefined for the type Method" and where is invoke "The method newInstance() is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: you need the imports I added on top (java.lang. ...)

Comment: I changed method.invoke(next.newInstance(), parameters); to method.invoke(((Class) next).newInstance(), parameters);

Comment: I had it but parametercount is not in [java.lang.reflect.Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

Comment: you are rigth, it's not any more available, I will edit it to a list

Comment: I still have problem with next.newInstance() because Object next doesnt has newInstance(). Cast to Class is Exception. :(